# UIView animations are not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, ios7, uiviewanimation

I'm using animations to change the frame of view for fadein and fadeout.But they are not working.
os:ios7

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.8 animations:^{
      [objArticleTable setFrame:CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX([objArticleTable frame]), CGRectGetMinY([objArticleTable frame]), CGRectGetWidth([objArticleTable frame]), 0)];}];
```

Comment: you set height of the frame to 0??? why?

Comment: i have changed it from 50 to 0

Comment: You can change `alpha` to make `fadeOut` and `fadeIn`..

Comment: are you performing the animation on the main thread?

Comment: consider using affine transform to perform the operation.

Comment: the code seems ok to me, how exactly it doesn't work? does it disappear without any animation, or the view just stays there? and is this code snippet inside another animation block?

Comment: Are you using AutoLayout?

Comment: check my answer and let me know it is working or not.. if it is not we can try another scenario

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
objArticleTable.alpha = 0.0f;
objArticleTable.hidden = NO;
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f
     animations:^{
         objArticleTable.alpha = 1.0;
     } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
          //Done
     }];
```

Answer (score 0):

For `fade-in` effect you can use

```
objArticleTable.alpha = 0.0f;
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.8 animations:^{
                                              [objArticleTable setFrame:CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX([objArticleTable frame]), CGRectGetMinY([objArticleTable frame]), CGRectGetWidth([objArticleTable frame]), 50)];}];
                                               objArticleTable.alpha = 1.0f; 
                                            }
 completion:nil];
```

And for `fade-out`

```
objArticleTable.alpha = 1.0f;
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.8 animations:^{
                                               [objArticleTable setFrame:CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX([objArticleTable frame]), CGRectGetMinY([objArticleTable frame]), CGRectGetWidth([objArticleTable frame]), 0)];}];
                                                objArticleTable.alpha = 0.0f; 
                                            }
     completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.. Use set frame only if you want to change the frames alpha will take of fadein and fadeout..

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:10.0f animations:^{
objArticleTable.alpha = 1.0f;
[objArticleTable setFrame:CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX([objArticleTable frame]),CGRectGetMinY([objArticleTable frame]), CGRectGetWidth([objArticleTable frame]), 50)];
}
completion:^(BOOL finished){
[UIView animateWithDuration:10.0f animations:^{
    objArticleTable.alpha = 0.0f;
[objArticleTable setFrame:CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX([objArticleTable frame]), CGRectGetMinY([objArticleTable frame]), CGRectGetWidth([objArticleTable frame]), 0)];
}];
}];
```